# how to save a function pointer with dyn parameters in a structure

Tags: rust

I'm getting

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:38:39
   |
37 |     fn set_source_outcome<S: Source, O: Outcome>(&mut self, selector: fn(s: &S) -> &O) {
   |                           - this type parameter
38 |         self.selector = Some(Box::new(selector));
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Source`, found type parameter `S`
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r (dyn Source + 'r)) -> &'r (dyn Outcome + 'r)`
              found fn pointer `for<'r> fn(&'r S) -> &'r O`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

when trying to save a function with dyn parameters in a structure, like this:

```rust
struct X {
    selector: Option<Box<fn(s: &dyn Source) -> &dyn Outcome>>,
}

impl X {
    fn set_source_outcome<S: Source, O: Outcome>(&mut self, selector: fn(s: &S) -> &O) {
        self.selector = Some(Box::new(selector));
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do so?
playground: [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b19f30c49829edd527f6fc612fb27599)

Comment: `selector()` takes concrete types. You want to give it `dyn Trait`. How do you expect that to succeed? What if the type will mismatch?

Comment: selector takes traits, the generics names were just same as tratis', renamed

Comment: No, they're generic parameters and will be monomrphized.

Comment: well, as soon as the problem in the subject is solved I'd be happy to have those params declared in any way possible

Answer (score 0):

ok, looks somewhat like [image]but still works [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7c7caffdef1afae1896536281ad30fb2)

a more straightforward solution is most welcome